# How do I calculations of high Low percentage of google stock

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

How do I calculations of high Low percentage of Alphabet's stock?

```
import pandas as pd
import quandl

df = quandl.get('WIKI/GOOGL')
df = df[['Adj. Open','Adj. High','Adj. Low','Adj. Close','Adj. Volume']]
df['HL_PCT'] = (df['Adj. High'] - df['Adj. Close']) / df['Adj. Close']*100.00
df['PCT_change'] = (df['Adj. Close'] - df['Adj. Open']) / df['Adj. Open ']*100.00
df = df[['Adj. Close','HL_PCT','HL_PCT','PCT_change','Adj. Volume']]

print(df.head())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is a little sloppy but I think this is what you want. 
But next time please read up on asking questions properly.

```
import quandl
df = quandl.get('WIKI/GOOGL')

df['HL_PCT'] = (df['Adj. High'] - df['Adj. Close']) / df['Adj. Close'] * 100.00
df['PCT_change'] = (df['Adj. Close'] - df['Adj. Open']) / df['Adj. Open'] * 100.00

print(df.head())
```

Comment: that's what is being done in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JcI5Vnw0b2c

Comment: Oh Okay now I see what you are trying to do. I edited my answer. If you look at where you divide by df["Adj. Open"] for getting the PCT_change there's a space.   So here's the code that'll work for what you're looking for.

Comment: When I run the code again on jupyter notebook it show an error

Comment: What error do you get? If it's a Quandl import error it just means you haven't installed Quandl correctly.